# Self thought Approach to making Binary Search tree but facing issues

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I need help, as to understand why my code isn't working. I tried to do this in dynamic queue based approach, not exactly a queue though. Where am I being wrong? ( or maybe my whole program is wrong)

So I think the logic which I am using currently is correct ( I tried a dry run that is trying to visualise what will happen in the code by drawing diagrams and stuff on paper) and I don't think that I am ignoring something,yet my program is stopping after the second execution line ( Add node line).

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/images/binary_search_tree.jpg

The left side of node/root is for smaller value ( I denote it by *a) and similarly right i.e greater value by *b. *c is for joining a node with the previous node or root.

```
struct node
{int val; node* a; node* b;node* c;};

class dqueue
{
node* root;
public:
dqueue()
{begin();}
void begin();
void insert();
void search();
};

void dqueue:: begin(){
node* first = new node;
cout << "Enter root element" << endl;
cin >> (first -> val);
root = first;
delete first; // This line is invalid as suggested by @Pawel Beza
  }

void dqueue :: insert()
 {
node* temp = new node;  
node* checker = new node;
// node* x = new node;
cout << "Enter the node element" << endl;
cin >> temp->val;
checker = root;
while(checker != NULL) 
  {if(temp -> val > checker -> val)
   {checker = checker -> b; }
 else if(temp -> val < checker -> val)
   {checker = checker -> a;} 
}
 if(checker == NULL)
  checker = temp;
 else if(temp -> val > checker -> val)
  checker -> b = temp;
 else if(temp -> val < checker -> val)
  checker -> a = temp;        
     }

  int main()
    {
     dqueue d;
     for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       {d.insert();}
      d.search();
      return 1;
           } 



  Enter root element
   8
  Enter the node element
   12

  // The program does not do anything after this line
  // After stopping the program I get the following line:
  waitid: no child processes
```

The search function is defined as:

```
void dqueue:: search()
{
  int i; node* checker = new node;
  cout << "Please enter element to be searched" << endl;
  cin >> i;
  checker = root;
  while(checker != NULL) 
  {
   if(i == checker -> val)
    {cout << "Value exists"<< endl;}   
   else if(i > checker -> val)
    {checker = checker -> b; }
   else if(i < checker -> val)
    {checker = checker -> a;} 
      }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to stay with your design of BST you should change few things:

### 1.`begin()` method

```
void dqueue:: begin() {
    node* first = new node;
    cout << "Enter root element" << endl;
    cin >> (first -> val);
    root = first;
    delete first;
}
```

By writing `root = first` you ensure that `root` and `first` points to the same part of memory, then you `delete first` which frees memory. So now `root` points to something which was deallocated by `delete` which probably causes issues which you mentioned.
Therefore proper code should be:

```
void dqueue:: begin() {
    root = new node;
    cout << "Enter root element" << endl;
    cin >> (root -> val);
}
```

### 2.`insert()` method

In your code there are 2 mistakes: firstly you don't consider what if you insert value which is already in BST tree(then it should insert it as a right child of existing value), secondly if you want to do it iteratively without use of double pointers you need to keep pointer `previous` which maintains the trailing pointer of `checker`. Therefore your code should look sth like this:

```
void dqueue :: insert() {
    node* temp = new node;
    node* checker = root;
    // Pointer y maintains the trailing
    // pointer of checker
    node * previous = NULL;

    cout << "Enter the node element" << endl;
    cin >> temp->val;

    while(checker != NULL) {
        previous = checker;
        if(temp -> val < checker -> val)
            checker = checker -> a;
        else
            checker = checker -> b;
    }

    if(temp -> val < previous -> val)
        previous->a = temp;
    else
        previous->b = temp;
}
```

### 3.`search()` method

The same as in previous method you didn't consider inserting value which is already in BST. Moreover you forgot to break after finding value.

```
void dqueue:: search()
{
  int i; node* checker = new node;
  cout << "Please enter element to be searched" << endl;
  cin >> i;
  checker = root;
  while(checker != NULL)
  {
    if(i == checker -> val) {
        cout << "Value exists"<< endl;
        break;
    }
    else if(i < checker -> val)
        checker = checker -> a;
    else
        checker = checker -> b;
}
```

As an **exercise** I would suggest to rethink this implementation because there are more elegant ways to implement *BST*. Therefore I highly recommend you to read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-1-search-and-insertion/) which may help you to avoid mistakes next time.

Comment: Yes sir, that was spot on. I removed the "delete first " line, and now the program works. Though right now I have no way as to check whether it is actually implemented or not. I have updated the search function (in the main question). No response from the search function. Please give your review